# Get question marks for special characters after trying several things. What else can I try?

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8, phpmyadmin, collation

I am struggling with the special character encoding on my website. I have an `input` field with a connected `datalist`. The `datalist` is populated from my database when the page is loaded. But somehow I get those question mark inside diamond symbols for each special character in the datalist options and normal question marks for special language characters (e.g. Chinese). Here is what I tried:

1. The initial dataset is a csv file, which I included in my database. I checked the collation in Notepad++ and it is set to *UTF8 without BOM*.
2. I am using phpmyadmin for database management. The server connection collation is set to *utf8mb4_bin*. The table where I store the data has the collation *utf8_bin*. And when I imported the data I made sure to use *utf8*. The characters are also displayed correctly in phpmyadmin.
3. In the `<head>` section of my index.php file I have also the following `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">`

But I still get those question marks. What else I could check??

Comment: use htmlentities()

Comment: Try: `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">`

Comment: @Thamilan Now the European special characters are displayed correctly. I thought they would be included in utf-8!? However, special language characters (e.g. Chinese) are still displayed in a normal question mark symbol (without the diamond around)

Answer (score 0):

You can easily check if the string you retrieve from DB is valid utf8 using this snippet.
If it is valid UTF-8 then your problem is in the presentation layer.

`if(mb_detect_encoding($str, 'UTF-8', true)){
  die('I\'m a valid UTF-8 string, YAY :D ');
}`

Comment: It's very hard to correctly detect character encodings, because of the massive overlap, and gaps that exist in the ranges of various encodings. While your answer is a good suggestion it is not a completely reliable result producer.

Comment: I completely agree, but since the question was quite vague this felt like a decent starting point.

Answer (score 0):

> I am using phpmyadmin for database management. The server connection collation is set to utf8mb4_bin. **The table where I store the data has the collation utf8_bin**. And when I imported the data I made sure to use utf8. The characters are also displayed correctly in phpmyadmin.

This is a likely cause, you want to change this to `utf8mb4_` *Collation*.

Other points are to use PHP `mb_` actions such as

```
mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8');
mb_http_output('UTF-8');
```

At the top of your PHP pages. Also be sure to set the *connection* character set in your Database connection object:

```
$this->MySQLiObjectVariable->set_charset("utf8mb4");
```

[`set_charset` Manual Page](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.set-charset.php)

What often happens is that while MySQL *storage* is set correctly and the PHP output is set correctly, the communication between the two is set as a system default which is often not the best character set for the given data (typically `latin1_` or `utf8_`).

Also it may be generally benefitial to ignore the Meta character set declaration and actually set them with a direct HTML header such as:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

appearing on your output page before the HTML content, ensuring the browser recieves the data as UTF-8.

Also read [UTF-8 all the way through](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through).

Comment: Thanks for the long answer. I tried to change everything to _utf8mb4_ and I tried to include the PHP mb_ actions, but it still didn't work out. The header information of the site I store in an extra header.php file which I include in each site.